# What are the tests we can perform in CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, testing, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-delivery

We want to build a CI/CD pipeline. And we want to include some automated and manual testing in it and we also do want to make a report based on automated testing. The full application is java microservice based and we are using Rest API here. Currently we are using

- Github
- Jira
- Jenkins

We are already practicing Junit test. What other automatic and manual tests do you suggest ? Please mention those sequentially and also please mention specifically whether the test belongs to CI part or CD part. And if any plugins of Jenkins can help, plz also mention that. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following setup, which is my standard opensource flow. Testing/scanning can occur in builds before code is merged during CI and also before it is released during CD.

Unit tests:

- As you are already doing with JUnit

Acceptance tests:

- [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) as a tool for testing, [allure plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/allure-jenkins-plugin/) to display automated test results. There is also [a plugin for creating cucumber tests in Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221264/cucumber-for-jira-bdd-natively-in-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)

Code quality:

- [Sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) for finding code smells, bugs, security hotspots etc. Can take an xml report from [Jacoco](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) to upload code coverage. Also has a [Jenkins plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/)

Vulnerability scanning for your dependencies:

- [OWASP dependency check](https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/) has a [plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/dependency-check-jenkins-plugin/) which publishes results

It is worth mentioning that these tools also have plugins for build tools, and sometimes IDEs and can be run locally - not just on Jenkins.